# query string sent to MVC controller gets encoded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I am new at the forum and also pretty new to MVC. 
I have an MVC app which runs OK while tested on my local development environment, but when deployed on IIS7 I am having some issues, one of it is that I get a 404 error when invoking an action from a controller passing parameters in the querystring, the "?" and "=" are encoded by IIS and I guess that's the reason why it is failing the call.
My controller action:

```
public ActionResult CreateMenu()
        {
            MenuModel.MenuItem menuItem;
            MenuModel.MenuItem childItem;

            if (AuthenticationService.IsUserAuthenticated())
            {
                string u_id = AuthenticationService.GetAuthenticatedUserName();
                Role u_role = Repository.GetUserRole(u_id);

                mainMenu.MenuItems.RemoveAt(0);
                if ((u_role.Role_Desc == "Administrator") || (u_role.Role_Desc == "Manager"))
                {
                    int lastMenuNumber = mainMenu.MenuItems.Count;
                    menuItem = new MenuModel.MenuItem(++lastMenuNumber, "Account Settings", "", "");
                    childItem = new MenuModel.MenuItem(++lastMenuNumber, "Log Report", "LogReporting", "ShowLog");
                    menuItem.ChildItems.Add(childItem);

                    childItem = new MenuModel.MenuItem(++lastMenuNumber, "User Permissions", "PermissionsSetting", "ListPermissions");
                    menuItem.ChildItems.Add(childItem);

                    mainMenu.MenuItems.Insert(0, menuItem);
                }
                // list of accessible BGs for selected client

                var selectedClient = Session["client_Id"] != null ?
                                        Repository.GetClientById((short)Session["client_Id"]) :
                                        Repository.GetUserClients(u_id).First();

                int i = 0;
                var bgs = Repository.GetUserClientAccesibleBusinessGroups(u_id, selectedClient.Client_ID);
                if (bgs.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var bg in bgs)
                    {                                                                                              

                        menuItem = new MenuModel.MenuItem(mainMenu.MenuItems.Count + 1, bg.BG_Desc, "FtpAccess", String.Format("Group/{0}?cbg={1}", selectedClient.Client_ID, bg.Client_BG_ID));
                        mainMenu.MenuItems.Insert(i++, menuItem);
                    }
                }
            }

            ViewData.Model = mainMenu;
            return View();
        }
```

This is used in a partial view  <% Html.RenderAction("CreateMenu", "Menu"); %> on the master view, which is rendered correctly, but when click on an item, the result is the 404 error.
One thing that I changed on the web.config was the settings for:
requestValidationMode="2.0" requestPathInvalidCharacters=""
because I was getting the error: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (?), after addindg those settings the Request.Path error disapear but now I am getting the 404.

Any help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you Url.Encoding the keys/values in the query string?

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode
```

can you paste the url which fails? You might have some invalid characters in the query string if you are not encoding it (e.g. '/') which might be causing the problem.

Comment: the url in the development environment: http://localhost:53170/FtpAccess/Group/14?cbg=19, turns this in the IIS server: http://someserver.int/FtpAccess/Group/14%253fcbg%3d19, IIS is encoding the character for "?" and "=". After some playing with the web.config of the app deployed in the server, I still have no luck, the 404 dissapear but other errors appear.